# In Scala enumerations how does one interpret 'val RED, GREEN, BLUE = Value'?

Tags: scala, enumeration

The defined way to describe an enumeration is the following:

```
object Color extends Enumeration{
  type Color = Value
  val RED, GREEN, BLUE = Value
}
```

What I don't understand is the structure of the last line. It seems like it creates a bunch of values and assigns them all the same value? But Value is a type so how does this work.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's unfortunate. If you consult the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L1) you'll see that `Value` is both a type (`abstract class` at line 184) as well as an overloaded method (lines 128 - 154).

Calling the `Value` method, without parameters, actually becomes a call to `new Val(i, name)`, so every one of your colors is assigned a "new," i.e. different, value.

Scala enumerations has undergone some [major rethinking](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1970) and looks likely to change in an upcoming release.